# Command button to look up and match data from a query to a table

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Can someone assist me with a VBA code that does the following?

Given query "Query1" and Table "Table1" in an Access DB
I would like to create a command button to loop through Query1, lookup and match a field.

```
Lookup [Query1].[number]=[Table1].[number]                    
set [Table1].[length]=[Query1].[Tlength]
```

For all the numbers in Query1

Not all numbers in Table1  exist in Query1

(I currently have the table1 fields in a form, if I made this operation in a query, I would not be able to add a new number entry in the form, that is why I would like to create macro command button on the form to update a length field in the table)

So when the command button is pressed table1 Tlength would be updated as such:

Query1:

```
Number | Length                                                         
N001   | 120                                         
N005   | 60                                        
N006   | 50        
ect.
```

Table1:

```
Number   |  Tlength            
N001     |   120              
N002     |  
N003     |                                        
N005     |   60                
N006     |   50                          
ect.
```

Comment: I have read your question twice, and honestly don't have a clue about what exactly you're trying to do. Are `Table1.length` and `Query1.Tlength` fields? Then you probably want an update query. Please provide sample data, an attempt, and the expected outcome.

Comment: Have you tried [Dlookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)?

Comment: Always illustrate needs with data (input data and desired result). Better to show than tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a quite simple update query.

If Query1 is an updateable query, we can use an `INNER JOIN` to construct our update query:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Query1 ON Table1.[Number] = Query1.[Number]
SET Table1.TLength = Query1.[Length]
```

However, if Query1 is not updateable, we will need to use a `DLookUp`:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.TLength = DLookUp("Length", "Query1", "[Number] = '" & [Number] & "'")
```

You can easily execute the SQL on a button click using either a macro or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it with the following code given that my Table1 is "Wire_Designation" with Number and Length and and Query1 is Total_Length_Query with Number and Tlength.  When I run it, it works.  However, if I try to save the database thereafter, the database gives me an error that I don't have exclusive access to the database, and I would have to close and reopen the database.  Does anyone know the reason?

```
  Dim MyRst As DAO.Recordset  
  Dim MyRst As Recordset
  Set MyRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Wire_Designation")
  MyRst.MoveFirst
  Do Until MyRst.EOF
     MyRst.Edit
     MyRst![Length] = DLookup("Tlength", "Total_Length_Query", "[Number] = '" & 
     MyRst![Number] & "'")
     MyRst.Update
     MyRst.MoveNext
  Loop
  MyRst.Close
  Set MyRst = Nothing
```